# fatal: packed object stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-сумма.pack is corrupt

Tags: git

при просмотре истории изменений файлов встретил ошибку (актуальные данные заменены словами для удобства):

> error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
>   error: failed to read object сумма1 at offset смещение from .git/objects/pack/pack-сумма2.pack
>   fatal: packed object сумма1 (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-сумма2.pack) is corrupt

есть полностью рабочие клоны этого репозитория. как восстановить данный экземпляр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

повреждён **только** архив с объектами (фактически, только один объект: *commit* или *tree* или *blob*). в данной ситуации проще всего будет его подменить из клона с актуальной информацией.

1. на всякий случай сохраните текущее содержимое каталога `.git/objects/pack`
2. скопируйте содержимое этого каталога из клона с актуальной информацией
3. проверьте, что «всё в порядке». например, так:

   ```
   $ git fsck --full --no-dangling
   Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
   Checking objects: 100% (11098/11098), done.
   ```
4. удалите сохранённое содержимое каталога

---

больше подробностей для более «тяжёлых» случаев:

- [Git User Manual - Git concepts - Recovering from repository corruption](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#recovering-from-repository-corruption)
- [How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/801577/4827341)
- [How do you restore a corrupted object in a git repository (for newbies)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3613682/4827341)

Comment: Перевод? Или вы сами столкнулись с такой проблемой?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сам.